# Kivy VKeyboard with blinking cursor and no double opening

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, virtual-keyboard

For touch screen text inputs I am using the kivy VKeyboard. Unfortunately there is no blinking cursor so the user don't know where he is typing at the moment (like in the picture). If someone will add some text, it's difficult to find the position (e.g.: change *"test"* to *"t e s t"*) Is there a way to add/enable a blinking cursor to the keyboard like in other applications?

Also, sometime the keyboard starts twice at the same time. Is it possible to prevent opening two keyboards at the same time?

[image]

I am using kivy 1.11.1 with python 3.5.3 on a Raspberry Pi 3+.

Best regards!